# checking if Index out of Range with array

Tags: java

I have written a program with a lot of operations on arrays. How I can check if I out of range with array, because I go Run Time Error at SPOJ.

Comment: Well the valid range of indexes is *always* 0 (inclusive) to `array.length` (exclusive).

Comment: So many unknowns here. I bet some people dont know what SPOJ is, and what Run Time Error at SPOJ means. It many not be a problem with array indexes but many other reason.

Comment: Checking the bounds is *a* solution.  Why you're getting errors when indexing into arrays may be indicative of a *bigger* problem, with which we would need more code to analyze to give you a more complete solution.

Answer (score 5):

Without knowing any more detailed context, the basic approach as outlined by Jon Skeet in the comments is something like the following:

```
if (index < 0 || index >= array.length) {
    //Index Out Of Range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no code to refer and see if you have gone out of range. Maybe you want to post your code for reference.

As long as your index is not of negative value and 1 value under the length of your array, you will be within bounds of your array.

For example an array of length 10, you have to minus 1 and able to call indexes between 0 - 9.

```
for(int x=0; x < yourArray.length; x++){
    //this for loop will nicely loop without going out of bounds unless your  
    //loop body contains something that will trigger the error. 
}
```